# How does bash's disown work?

Tags: bash, disown

On a Linux system, the bash builtin command `disown` can be used to remove jobs from the current session. How does bash implement this feature? Is `setsid()` used here, and if so, how does bash trigger the child process to invoke `setsid()`? Does it use signal?

Comment: Did you already look at [the source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/jobs.def#n233) but can't understand it?

Answer (score 5):

No. `disown` does **not** remove a job from the current session [1], does not detach it from the terminal, and does not affect which signals the kernel will send it when the session leader exits or when the controlling terminal is torn down.

`disown` only works on bash's own job table, only changes bash's idea of which jobs it's in control of, and only affects bash's own behavior, namely which jobs it will resend a `SIGHUP` received by the bash process. That `SIGHUP` resending is an extra feature of `bash` [2], not required by the standard and not related to the job control provided by the OS.

You can see it with a simple example, where I'm using `script(1)` to create a pty and an interactive shell session running in it:

```
$ script /dev/null -qc bash
$ sh -c 'sleep 555 & sleep .1; kill -STOP $!; trap "echo hupped!" HUP; sleep 666' &
[1] 3837
$ disown -a
$ jobs
   # no jobs known to bash
$ pgrep -as0
   # show all processes from the current session
3836 bash
3837 sh -c sleep 555 & sleep .1; kill -STOP $!; trap "echo hupped!" HUP; sleep 666
3838 sleep 555
3841 sleep 666
$ kill -HUP $$
   # seppuku the session leader
Hangup
hupped!
```

Here the kernel sends a `SIGHUP` signal to the background process group (= job) because one of its processes is stopped, and disowning it will *not* prevent that from happening.

All processes from the `sh -c '...'` are part of the same job, including the "background" `sleep &`; shell scripts don't do job control by default.

If no members of the background process group are stopped, no `SIGHUP` is sent:

```
$ script /dev/null -qc bash
$ sh -c 'sleep 555 & trap "echo hupped!" HUP; sleep 666' &
[1] 3270
$ disown -a
$ kill -HUP $$
    # sleep 555, 666 and sh -c are still running
```

Finally, bash will send a `SIGHUP` to all the jobs from its table (only those started by itself and not disowned), no matter if bash is the session leader or not, or if the jobs are running, stopped, etc:

```
$ bash
$ sh -c 'sleep 555 & trap "echo hupped!" HUP; sleep 666' &
[1] 3413
$ kill -HUP $$
Hangup
hupped!
Hangup
```

[1] which would be impossible to do anyway; `setsid()` is only able to make into a new session a process which is *not* a process group leader, there is no way to move a whole job into a new or existing session.

[2] which is documented in the bash's manpage:

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`.   Before  exiting,
>          an  interactive  shell  resends  the  `SIGHUP`  to  all  jobs, running or
>          stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the
>          `SIGHUP`.   To  prevent the shell from sending the signal to a particular
>          job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the  `disown`  builtin
>          (see  SHELL  BUILTIN  COMMANDS  below)  or marked to not receive `SIGHUP`
>          using `disown -h`.

There's is also `shopt -s huponexit` which cause a *login* bash shell to send a `HUP` to its jobs upon exiting (whether because of a signal or not), which again overlaps in confusing ways with the standard job control features of the OS.