# Without nohup on csh, background job still running after ssh exits

Tags: linux, ssh, signals, csh, nohup

I'm trying to understand the need for using `nohup` with background commands in ssh. My shell is csh on CentOS.

1. The background command below continues running even after ssh exits. I was expecting this to only happen if `nohup` was prefixing the command.

   What's the scenario where `nohup` would be needed?

   ```
    ssh host 'sleep 80 >& /dev/null &'
   ```
2. I also tried an interactive shell, and the PID of the background job still exists on host after the ssh exits.

   ```
    ssh host sleep 80 >& /dev/null & exit
   ```
3. I also tried terminating the interactive session with `kill -HUP PID` rather than `exit`, and the PID of the background job still exists on host after the ssh exits.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a *background* process group (job) is NOT killed by default when the session leader (the shell) exits, or when its controlling terminal is torn down.

There are only some special cases when that happens:

**(1)** The background job is *stopped*, in which case it will be sent a `SIGHUP`/`SIGCONT` pair of signals by the *kernel*. If the `SIGHUP` signal is not caught or ignored by a process, the process will terminate.

The definition of a stopped job is: any job containing a stopped process. A process *sleeping* on a blocking system call like `nanosleep(2)` or `read(2)` is NOT considered stopped.

**(2)** A process tries to read or write to the terminal which no longer exists, and exits (of its own volition) because of the errors it gets when trying to do so.

**(3)** The job is actually a *foreground* job. The *kernel* sends a `SIGHUP` signal to the foreground process group when the session leader / controlling process (ie the shell) terminates. The controlling process is itself signaled with `SIGHUP` when its controlling terminal is torn down, which usually causes it to terminate.

Even commands started with `&` are actually part of the *foreground* process group when they're started from a shell with no job control (which in most shells --but not in csh-- is the default when running *scripts* and *subshells*).

**(4)** You're using a shell like `bash` or `zsh`, which goes out of its way to send a `SIGHUP` signal to all its jobs when it's itself signaled with `SIGHUP` (per point 3. above, the shell being the controlling process), or simply when it exits (the latter only the default in `zsh`, but not the default and subject to the `shopt huponexit` option in bash).

The **csh shell** (either the real `csh` or `tcsh`) **does not have that behaviour** from `bash` or `zsh`. In `tcsh` (but NOT in the real `csh`) you can start a command with the `hup` builtin in order to have it hup'ed when the shell exits:

```
tcsh% hup sleep 3600 &
tcsh% exit
$ pgrep sleep
[nothing]
```

**(5)** Your init system goes out of its way to cleanup any terminated user sessions. In its default configuration, **systemd** will signal all the processes from a *scope* with a `SIGTERM` followed by a `SIGKILL` after a delay, so `nohup` will NOT help you with that anyway. Also, systemd's idea of a *scope* doesn't match a Unix process session, so running a command with `setsid(1)` will not let it escape it, either.

You can probably change systemd's behaviour by tweaking away from their defaults the `KillUserProcesses=yes`, `KillMode=control-group`, `KillSignal=SIGTERM` and `SendSIGKILL=yes` options.

Comment: Thanks. So, in real csh: what's the scenario where nohup would be needed? Is it not needed for real csh?

Comment: (1) and (3). And (5) with a specially configured systemd.

Comment: FWIW, notice that `nohup` is a __builtin__ in csh, and does NOT do some of the actions that a standalone `nohup` program may do (like redirect stdout and stderr, and maybe even stdin). It's a perfectly fine idea to read the [`csh(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/csh.1#nohup) manpage, too. And in general, `nohup` is not some magic tool -- it just starts a program with `SIGHUP` ignored. The standalone `nohup` is also subject to nasty [races](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316).

Comment: If you find anything dubious in this answer, please put up directly. Don't let it "float". They were already similar questions like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568299/308316) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/542617/308316).

Comment: Especially this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568299/when-to-use-nohup/568332#comment1057169_568332) applies here too.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! ->For csh, "all processes detached with ‘&’ are effectively nohup'ed."

Comment: For the case (1) you mentioned: I tried that (kiling PID using HUP signal) which is "3." in my question, but the PID of the background job still exists on host after the ssh exits. This leaves cases (3) and (5) that you mentioned. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. The "effectively nohupped" from the csh(1) manpage is a bit of hyperbole. If the background process is _stopped_, it will be _hupped_ (and terminated if it doesn't catch the HUP signal). To see that in action, run `ssh -t localhost csh`, and inside the csh, run `sleep 3600 &` followed by `kill -TSTP $!`, and then either exit the shell (ignoring the warning about stopped jobs) or break the ssh connection by pressing `<Enter>`, `~` and `.`. The stopped `sleep` process will be killed. Thence, the case __(1)__ applies to csh, too.

Comment: I tried that and can't get it to follow the behavior you're describing. Anything I'm doing wrong? https://www.picpasteplus.com/v.php?i=6c74116315

Also, I'm concerned about the ssh from the origin host getting killed (machine going down). The background task is still there on the destination host, without explicit nohup.

Comment: You didn't actually exit the csh shell. csh warned you that there are stopped jobs and refused to exit. You should enter `exit` again. Or simply break the ssh connection with `~.` at the beginning of the line, as described (no, that won't kill the ssh server ;-)) Instead of ssh you can use script(1), a terminal emulator, a tmux or screen window, etc.

Comment: Thank you, exiting with "~." is now showing the behavior you described with the ssh -t.  <br>
For non-interactive ssh sessions like the one I mentioned in "1.": ssh host 'sleep 80 >& /dev/null &'. Is nohup needed?  <br>
Regarding the concern about the ssh from the origin host getting killed (machine going down). The background task is still there on the destination host, without explicit nohup. Does that mean nohup is not needed in this scenario?

Comment: @neo_coder yes, it's needed even for non-interactive sessions IF the async/bg process may be stopped and your login shell does job control even when in non-interactive mode. Like csh does ;-) Or, a bit different from your 1. example, if the bg process is not stopped and the shell is NOT interactive and is not doing  job control, but you're running ssh with the `-t` option.

Comment: Instead of trying to tell apart all those special cases, just run daemons as daemons (detached from the terminal, in their own session, with their standard fds redirected to /dev/null, etc). It makes NO SENSE to pretend that the background jobs (an abstraction intended for interactive shells), or the shell's `&` syntax should be used to spawn long-running, non-interactive processes.